# How to specify package/derivation runtime dependencies with Nix?

Tags: nix

I'm making a haskell program and I'm setting `buildInput` like this to include `pkgs.ffmpeg-full`:

```
(myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "App" (./.) {}).overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
  buildInputs = (oldAttrs.buildInputs or []) ++ [ pkgs.ffmpeg-full ];
})
```

However this seems to make the ffmpeg package accessible during *build time only* rather than runtime of the application.

What attribute do I need to set for `ffmpeg-full` to be available during runtime - being able to invoke the `ffmpeg` executable?

There is a section about runtime dependencies in nix pills but I don't understand that section, it doesn't make sense how it can always determine runtime dependencies by hashes alone? I mean if I reference an executable in a shell script - surely nix does not parse the shell script to determine the executable I reference. https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/automatic-runtime-dependencies.html#idm140737320205792

> Something is different for runtime dependencies however. Build
> dependencies are automatically recognized by Nix once they are used in
> any derivation call, but we never specify what are the runtime
> dependencies for a derivation.
>
> There's really black magic involved. It's something that at first
> glance makes you think "no, this can't work in the long term", but at
> the same time it works so well that a whole operating system is built
> on top of this magic.
>
> In other words, Nix automatically computes all the runtime
> dependencies of a derivation, and it's possible thanks to the hash of
> the store paths.

Comment: Yes, nix does scan your outputs for hashes. As said, it works really well. I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: "for ffmpeg-full to be available during runtime?"

What you need depends on whether you're linking to it or invoking an executable.

Comment: In this case it's invoking an executable.

Comment: Could I ask for a runnable [mre]? There are some Haskell-specific complexities to using the nixpkgs `makeWrapper` in a Cabal build.

Answer (score 2):

default.nix:

```
{
  ghc ? "ghc8106",
  pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}
}:
with pkgs.haskell.lib;
let
  haskellPkgs = pkgs.haskell.packages.${ghc};
  inherit (pkgs) lib;

  mySourceRegexes = [
    "^app.*$"
    "^.*\\.cabal$"
    "package.yaml"
  ];

  myApp = (haskellPkgs.callCabal2nix "my-hello"
    (lib.sourceByRegex ./. mySourceRegexes) { });

in myApp
   .overrideAttrs(
      oa: {
        nativeBuildInputs = oa.nativeBuildInputs ++ [pkgs.hello pkgs.makeWrapper];
        installPhase = oa.installPhase + ''
          ln -s ${pkgs.hello.out}/bin/hello $out/bin/hello
        '';
        postFixup = ''
          wrapProgram $out/bin/x-exe --prefix PATH : ${pkgs.lib.makeBinPath [ pkgs.hello ]}
        '';
      })
```

src/Main.hs:

```
module Main where

import System.Process (callCommand)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "HELLO"
  callCommand "hello"
  putStrLn "BYE"
```

Comment: This seems to have 0 mention of ffmpeg which is the dependency that I was trying to add?

Comment: this is generalized version for any executable replace hello with ffmpeg

Comment: Can you explain the answer? What does `makeWrapper` do? What is `x-exe`? What does `lib.makeBinPath` do? What if my derivation output does not have a `bin` folder?

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is not directly supported with an explicitly stated list of dependencies. However we can indirectly achieve this with "wrapping".

---

I found more information about wrapping here: https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Cookbook#Wrapping_packages

So I can do a `ls` that references the package.

```
...
appPkg = (myHaskellPackages.callCabal2nix "HaskellNixCabalStarter" (./.) {}).overrideAttrs (oldAttrs: {
  buildInputs = (oldAttrs.buildInputs or []) ++ [ pkgs.ffmpeg-full ];
  });
in
(pkgs.writeScriptBin "finderapp" ''
  #!${pkgs.stdenv.shell}

  ls ${pkgs.ffmpeg-full}/bin/ffmpeg
  exec ${appPkg}/bin/app
''
)
```

We can verify the built package(?) correctly depends on the appropriate with:

```
nix-store -q --references result
/nix/store/0cq84xic2absp75ciajv4lfx5ah1fb59-ffmpeg-full-4.2.2
/nix/store/rm1hz1lybxangc8sdl7xvzs5dcvigvf7-bash-4.4-p23
/nix/store/wlvnjx53xfangaa4m5rmabknjbgpvq3d-HaskellNixCabalStarter-0.1.0.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're doing here constitutes wrapping your script in a particularly useful way. See the nixpkgs helpers that create wrapper scripts that update the PATH and then call your "real" script (under a different name).

Comment: See in particular https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#fun-makeWrapper