# NixOS service systemd unit's $PATH does not contain expected dependency

Tags: nix, nixos

I have the following definition:

```
  hello123 = 
    (pkgs.writeScriptBin "finderapp" ''
      #!${pkgs.stdenv.shell}
      # Call hello with a traditional greeting 
      ls ${pkgs.ffmpeg-full}/bin/ffmpeg

      ffmpeg --help

      echo hello
    ''
    );
```

And the service:

```
  systemd.services = {
    abcxyz = {
      enable = true;
      description = "abcxyz";
      serviceConfig = {
        WorkingDirectory = "%h/temp/";
        Type      = "simple";
        ExecStart = "${hello123}/bin/finderapp";
        Restart   = "always";
        RestartSec   = 60;
      };
      wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
    };
  };
```

However, this seems to fail being able to execute `ffmpeg`:

```
Jul 10 19:47:54 XenonKiloCranberry systemd[1]: Started abcxyz.
Jul 10 19:47:54 XenonKiloCranberry finderapp[10042]: /nix/store/9yx9s5yjc6ywafadplblzdfaxqimz95w-ffmpeg-full-4.2.3/bin/ffmpeg
Jul 10 19:47:54 XenonKiloCranberry finderapp[10042]: /nix/store/bxfwljbpvl21wsba00z5dm9dmshsk3bx-finderapp/bin/finderapp: line 5: ffmpeg: command not found
Jul 10 19:47:54 XenonKiloCranberry finderapp[10042]: hello
```

Why is this failing? I assume it's correctly getting `ffmpeg` as a runtime dependency (verified with `nix-store -q --references ...`) as stated in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68330101/1663462

---

If I add a `echo $PATH` to the script, it outputs the following:

```
Jul 10 19:53:44 XenonKiloCranberry finderapp[12011]: /nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/bin:/nix/store/97vambzyvpvrd9wgrrw7i7svi0s8vny5-findutils-4.7.0/bin:/nix/store/srmjkp5pq8c055j0lak2hn0ls0fis8yl-gnugrep-3.4/bin:/nix/store/p34p7ysy84579lndk7rbrz6zsfr03y71-gnused-4.8/bin:/nix/store/vfzp1mavwiz5w3v10hs69962k0gwl26c-systemd-243.7/bin:/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/sbin:/nix/store/97vambzyvpvrd9wgrrw7i7svi0s8vny5-findutils-4.7.0/sbin:/nix/store/srmjkp5pq8c055j0lak2hn0ls0fis8yl-gnugrep-3.4/sbin:/nix/store/p34p7ysy84579lndk7rbrz6zsfr03y71-gnused-4.8/sbin:/nix/store/vfzp1mavwiz5w3v10hs69962k0gwl26c-systemd-243.7/sbin
```

Or these paths basically:

```
/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/bin
/nix/store/97vambzyvpvrd9wgrrw7i7svi0s8vny5-findutils-4.7.0/bin
/nix/store/srmjkp5pq8c055j0lak2hn0ls0fis8yl-gnugrep-3.4/bin
/nix/store/p34p7ysy84579lndk7rbrz6zsfr03y71-gnused-4.8/bin
/nix/store/vfzp1mavwiz5w3v10hs69962k0gwl26c-systemd-243.7/bin
/nix/store/x0jla3hpxrwz76hy9yckg1iyc9hns81k-coreutils-8.31/sbin
/nix/store/97vambzyvpvrd9wgrrw7i7svi0s8vny5-findutils-4.7.0/sbin
/nix/store/srmjkp5pq8c055j0lak2hn0ls0fis8yl-gnugrep-3.4/sbin
/nix/store/p34p7ysy84579lndk7rbrz6zsfr03y71-gnused-4.8/sbin
/nix/store/vfzp1mavwiz5w3v10hs69962k0gwl26c-systemd-243.7/sbin
```

Which shows that ffmpeg is not in there.

Comment: Call `${pkgs.ffmpeg-full}/bin/ffmpeg --help`. Best practice is not to rely on PATH lookups unnecessarily.

Comment: (Same reasoning behind nix best practices using `rpath` when dynamically linking instead of trying to build a LD_LIBRARY_PATH to dependencies)

Comment: Is there an alternative to that? The question is a simplified example. Right now I have a built app that relies on `ffmpeg` being accessible in the PATH.

Comment: The usual approach is for the derivation for that app to itself include a wrapper that puts ffmpeg in its PATH before starting the real/underlying executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the previous answers

- not using `PATH`
- adding to `PATH` via systemd config

you can add it to the `PATH` inside the wrapper script, making the script more self-sufficient and making the extended `PATH` available to subprocesses, if ffmpeg or any other command needs it (probably not in this case).

The `ls` command has no effect on subsequent commands, like it shouldn't.

What you want is to add it to `PATH`:

```hs
  hello123 = 
    (pkgs.writeScriptBin "finderapp" ''
      #!${pkgs.stdenv.shell}
      # Call hello with a traditional greeting 
      PATH="${pkgs.ffmpeg-full}/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"

      ffmpeg --help

      echo hello
    ''
    );
```

The part `${PATH:+:${PATH}}` takes care of the `:` and pre-existing `PATH`, if there is one. The simplistic `:${PATH}` could effectively add `.` to `PATH` when it was empty, although that would be rare.

Comment: Although this is a solution, it seems like a workaround. Is there maybe a reason why this does not work in a systemd unit context? As like mentioned the expected dependency is listed when doing `nix-store -q --references...`?

Comment: These things (bash, Nix, PATH) work as intended. By what mechanism did you expect your `finderapp` script to find `ffmpeg` without setting `PATH`?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is the most elegant solution as the dependencies have to be known in the service definition instead of the package/derivation, but it's a solution none the less.

We can add additional paths with `path = [ pkgs.ffmpeg-full ];`:

```
abcxyz = {
  enable = true;
  description = "abcxyz";
  path = [ pkgs.ffmpeg-full ];
  serviceConfig = {
    WorkingDirectory = "%h/temp/";
    Type      = "simple";
    ExecStart = "${hello123}/bin/finderapp";
    Restart   = "always";
    RestartSec   = 60;
  };
  wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
};
```